Android Studio Evaluate Expression issue
I am using Android Studio for Flutter development, and I can't debug code lately! I can set breakpoints but can't see what data is inside the object.
Ex: I have one object for (this happens for every objects) couponItem and whenever I try to debug that, I don't see anything at all in the evaluate expression dialog or debugger.
I am using following versions on MacBook pro.
Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2412.12266719, built on August 22, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.intellij.marketplace (241.18034.106)
  Dart (241.18808)
  com.github.copilot (1.5.22.6765)
  zielu.gittoolbox (500.2.15+233)
  io.flutter (81.0.2)



There is a bug in Flutter plugin for a long time with no doubt.A workaround is using older version Flutter and Dart plugins that will help. However, you also have to downgrade your Android Studio. Download urls are as follows.

Android Studio: Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2https://developer.android.com/studio/archive
Flutter: 77.1.3https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions
Dart: 232.10313https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart/versions

After downgrading, you can install downloaded plugins from your disk on Android Studio, please follow the steps:

Setting
Plugins
GEAR button (on the top-right)
Install Plugin from Disk...
Restart Android Studio

Done!
